# Need help with Hilbert-style proof.

Tags: hilbert-calculus

Given ¬q and (¬p⇒(¬q⇒¬r)), prove (r⇒p).

Do any of you know how to do this? I appreciate whatever help you can provide me.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm unfortunately uncertain where to even begin. I would appreciate whatever help anyone can provide.